# Error en el backend al actualizar simultáneamente varios documentos con Javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, mongoose, react-hooks

desde el backend estoy tratando de actualizar en MongoDB el campo "cantidad" en varios documentos, datos que son enviados desde el frontend con React Hooks. Si actualizo solo un documento lo permite sin problema, pero cuando son varios documentos me genera error 500.
Traigo el Id (const productId = req.params.id) para que encuentre el Documento y traigo la cantidad (const Cantidad = req.body.cantidad) que es el valor a actualizar. Cuando hay un solo Id lo actualiza, pero sin son varios ya no lo permite. Como va entonces el código. Muchas gracias

```
`router.put(
  '/cantidad/:id',
  isAuth,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const productId = req.params.id;
    const Cantidad = req.body.cantidad;
    const producto = await Product.findById(productId);
    if (producto) {
      producto.cantidad = Number(Cantidad);
      const editaProduct = await producto.save();
      res.send({ message: 'Producto Modificado', producto: editaProduct });
    } else {
      res.status(404).send({ message: 'Producto no existe' });
    }
  })
);`
```

Comment: Evidentemente, tu router recibe por params(Y ASÍ TIENE QUE SER) un solo id para lo cual si funciona correctamente, si deseas actualizar un grupo de documentos con una lista de IDs, busca otra manera de pasar esos datos

Comment: Gracias Victor Hugo Tirado por el interés, que me aconsejaría, no se me ocurre. Aunque un console.log, me muestra que si consigo traer varios IDs al igual que las cantidades